# Huawei Mediapad M1 won't hard reset

Tags: lock-screens, recovery-mode, factory-reset, huawei, hard-reset

I just bought a used Huawei Mediadpad M1 and it still has a lock screen from the seller. Unfortunately he won't write back any more so I need to hard reset it. I found in the forums these steps:

1. Switch off the device.
2. Press power button + Volume up button until the device is switched on (followed by a small vibration).
3. As soon as the device is switched on, let go of the power switch but keep pressing the volume up button.
4. After a few seconds, a screen will appear showing a green android symbol with rotating gears. When this screen appears let go the volume up button and keep pressing volume down button.
5. Hold like this for a few seconds. till a big green 'OK' appears on the screen.

I did and I also tried a few other things but this is the only method where I at least access the recovery mode (almost). Instead ot the big green OK i just get the opposite, a bit red FAIL.

[image]

The error message sais something about an SD card. Do I need to insert one for a hard reset? I actually can't imagine that since all the guides out there say to remove any SIM or SD card before hard resetting the tablet.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Okay, in the meanwhile I got that the tablet tried to update. I put the most recent firmware on an SD card but the manager says this version cannot be updated. And actually this is not what I'd like to do, I just want to do a hard- or factory reset. Whatever gives me control of the tablet and deletes all the data from its last owner.